# How to use NSDictionary item object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have parsed some JSON values and I'm using the following code to print these values.

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [item2 objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary* item;
while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
NSLog(@"First name = %@",  [item objectForKey:@"f_name"]);
NSLog(@"Image url = %@",  [item objectForKey:@"img_url"]);
NSLog(@"Message body = %@",[item objectForKey:@"msg_body"]);
}
```

Every item has more than one object, so the **NSLogs** within the loop print

```
First name = f_name1
Image url = img_url1
Message body = msg_body1

First name = f_name2
Image url = img_url2
Message body = msg_body2

First name = f_name3
Image url = img_url3
Message body = msg_body3
```

I want to use the individual elements of these item objects to some labels.For example:

```
[label-1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", f_name1]]; 
[label-2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", f_name2]];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like you already have covered, can't see in wich part need help

Comment: You asked exactly the same question yesterday.  You still haven't really explained what exactly what output you're trying to accomplish. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517845/how-to-use-nsdictionary-item-values)

Answer (score 0):

every time when it enters the loop create UILabel programmetically, assign new frame and set text accordingly.

or you can use mutable array store all the dictionary values in mutable array. Using for loop and value of i u can assign value to a Label.